# CS1502 and CS1503: is it me or the compiler?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Here is my code, edited for brevity:

```
_cvList = new List<MyCollectionView<MnpsCell>>();
        void SetStuff<C, T>(Action<int?> SetKey, float y, float h=70) where C : MnpsCell
    {
        ...
        var mcv = new MyCollectionView<C>(frame, lineLayout, false);
        mcv.Delegate = new MyDelegate<C, T>(SetKey);
        mcv.DataSource = new MyDataSource2<C, T>();
        mcv.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(C), new NSString(typeof(C).Name));
        ...
        _cvList.Add(mcv);
    }
```

Here are the errors I'm getting on the `_cvList.Add(mcv);` line:

- `Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for System.Collections.Generic.List<SimpleCollectionView.MyCollectionView<SimpleCollectionView.MnpsCell>>.Add(SimpleCollectionView.MyCollectionView<SimpleCollectionView.MnpsCell>) has some invalid arguments (CS1502)`
- `Error CS1503: Argument #1 cannot convert SimpleCollectionView.MyCollectionView<C> expression to type SimpleCollectionView.MyCollectionView<SimpleCollectionView.MnpsCell> (CS1503)`

Since C is a MnpsCell, this does not make sense to me. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to indicate where `C` and `T` are used to better understand why those are generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is because MyCollectionView is not covariant.

To make this happen you need to define an Interface with the [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) modifier

```
interface IMyCollectionView<out T>
{ ... }
```

And then make your list look like this:

```
_cvList = new List<IMyCollectionView<MnpsCell>>();
```

Another approach would be create a nongeneric interface.

**Edit** As mentioned by D Stanley in comments, all methods of that interface can only return T. None of them is allowed to take T as an argument.
If you are stuck with this problem you might need to split up the interfaces.

Comment: There's more to it that just adding `out` - the methods of the interface must only _return_ `T`s - there cannot be any methods that use `T` as an input parameter.

Comment: You could seperate those into a different interface though. But you are right.